# Can I invite a friend to visit me in the UK?

Tags: uk, accommodation, standard-visitor-visas, invitation-letters

How long I need to live and work in the UK to be able to send an invitation to my friend from Algeria to visit me? Do I need any qualifications to send an invitation?  Right now, I have only been in the UK for three months, two of them working officially, and I am renting a room.

Answer (score 4):

There is no minimum residence requirement to invite a friend to visit - only that the person inviting the visitor should not be in breach of U.K. immigration rules. The person you are inviting must qualify for a Standard Visit Visa in their own right; if you are going to be supporting them during the visit eg providing funds, accommodation etc you will need to prove you have the resources to fulfil the commitment eg permission from your landlord. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules